# apt-get can't install 'libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid' dependecies

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, mesa

I'm trying to install 'libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid' on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with apt-get but I get this error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation 
or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required 
packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid : Depends: mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid (=10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid (= 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've tried to install each listed package individually and apt-get only complains about mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid. When I try to manually install that one I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have run apt-get update and upgrade.
I'm running on a nearly new install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS with just some nvidia graphics drivers and another graphics program installed. I have also run apt-show-versions on all the packages involved:

```
gstreamer1.0-clutter:amd64/trusty 2.0.8-1build1 uptodate
libcheese-gtk23:amd64/trusty 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 uptodate
libcheese7:amd64/trusty 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 uptodate
libclutter-gst-2.0-0:amd64/trusty 2.0.8-1build1 uptodate
libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64/trusty-updates 1.4.4-3ubuntu2.2 uptodate
libcogl-pango15:amd64/trusty 1.16.2-1 uptodate
libcogl15:amd64/trusty 1.16.2-1 uptodate
libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-vivid not installed
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:amd64/trusty-updates 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2 uptodate
mesa-common-dev-lts-vivid not installed
unity-control-center:amd64/trusty-updates 14.04.3+14.04.20140922-0ubuntu1.1 uptodate
```

They all seem to be a valid version for the install

Answer (score 0):

Check if the versions of dependent packages are matching with your installed versions.

Answer (score 0):

So it is fixed now. I uninstalled everything with an apt-get --purge remove and then reinstalled things with aptitude. I had to try several aptitude options for how to handle the dependencies but eventually one worked.